# Failed to open TCP connection to :443 (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 443)

Tags: heroku, actionmailer, sidekiq

Using Heroku and Rails 5.2, Sidekiq for background jobs. Job completes. Trying to send an email. Works from the console, but inside the worker, I am getting a consistent error.

Any idea what causes that error? Strange that the production console works, but the same code in the worker fails.

---

## Solved

Was actually a rogue unauthenticated API call in the worker.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are missing the address you are trying to connect, messages says `connection refused for nil port 443`, instead of nil it should have de address. And, also, before the port number it should have de address too, like: `Failed to open TCP connection to address:443`.